# Parameters are empty when submitting request for adapter authentication on Android

Tags: xamarin, ibm-mobilefirst

I use adapter authentication in my Xamarin.Forms app with the IBM MFP SDK. The adapter requires a username and a password.

In my iOS app (with the exact same shared code) everything works as it should.

In my Android app the parameters are empty (found that out using Charles / Fiddler).

I debugged the process and my `Identity` variable with username and password is not null and correctly filled in.

```
public override AdapterAuthenticationInfo GetAdapterAuthenticationParameters()
        {
            var parameters = new string[] { Identity.Email, Identity.Password };
            var invocationData = new WorklightProcedureInvocationData("AuthAdapter", "submitAuthentication", parameters);

            var authInfo = new AdapterAuthenticationInfo();
            authInfo.InvocationData = invocationData;

            return authInfo;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running your app using object array instead of string array and see if that works?

```
var parameters = new object[] { Identity.Email, Identity.Password };
```